# What to do when i always have an eye on me?

Tags: work-environment, phone

I have been working at this tuition center for about 2 years now. I am a decent worker who is never late and I always finish my assigned tasks.  There is a rule that was implemented from the start of my employment that says no phone usage during work.  I usually abide by this rule.

There are other employees in the center and when its a slow day, they will use their phones to play games or text. However, when I start using my phone, my supervisor calls out my name and tells me to not use my phone. I find this rather uncalled for, since everyone else is using their phone.

I have talked to my supervisor about this matter and she tells me that she isn't just doing this to me; sometimes this gets humiliating.

So what do I do in these types of situations?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> So what do I do in these type of situation?

Follow orders is usually the best policy. It makes no difference whether others are getting away with it or not. It's not work related so you have no real comeback if you're told not to do it.

Comment: This seems like wholly wrong advice to me. We don't have all the facts, but the OP describes being reprimanded for phone use when *they have finished all their work* and *their nearby peers are using their phones openly without reprimand*, by a manager who then denies the selective enforcement to the OP's face. None of that serves any business purpose, but sounds more like straightforward bullying by the OP's manager - forcing the OP to simply sit still and do nothing (even while surrounded by others playing games) as a means of humiliation, then denying it to dare the OP to call her on it.

Comment: The right response to a manager who is bullying you in this way *might* be to meekly accept the abuse and try to ignore it, if you need your job to survive and can't safely escalate the situation to a higher level of management without risking being fired. But most of us, thankfully, do not work in desperate cirumstances where we must accept any and all mistreatment just to live. Most of us, faced with this kind of abuse, should escalate the situation to higher management, and if that fails, change jobs. (Some people, in some circumstances, would add "sue the old employer" as well.)